# Can't find android block in build.gradle of Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I created a flutter project using `flutter create my_app`, which gives me a perfectly working Flutter Demo Home Page with a *counter* example.
I am now testing deployment of the app following the official documentation. I have created a keystore and a `key.properties` file as required, but I can't find the `android` block in the `build.grandle` file mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle).
I tried building the app and starting it on my phone but the `build.gradle` is still missing the `android` block.
Should I add it manually or did I possibly miss a step?

EDIT:
This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The file is `android/app/build.gradle` and not `/android/build.gradle`.

**Sorry**